# Math-related Javascript working in all browsers except Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm having issues with a custom bit of JS running in all browsers but IE10 (probably not working in previous versions either). I have run the debug and fixed the "errors "it threw up but seeing they had no effect on fixing the issue I reverted to the old version.

Tested in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari (Most recent Windows versions) with no issues, it's just IE screwing it over, if anyone could give suggestions I'd be very appreciative, thanks.

Edit: Let me try this again, seems people think I haven't spent time researching this.

The code (removed all styling):

```
<form>
<div>Crates: <output name="crates">0</output><br />
Skates: <output name="skates">0</output></div>
<div>
    <label for="desks">Desks</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="desks" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="pedestals">Pedestals</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="pedestals" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="drawers">Individual Drawers</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="drawers" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="credenzas">Credenzas</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="credenzas" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="cabinets">Storage Cabinets</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="cabinets" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="shelves">Shelves</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="shelves" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="smbookcases">Small Bookcases</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="smbookcases" value="0" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="lgbookcases">Large Bookcases</label><br />
    <input type="number" name="lgbookcases" value="0" />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="crates.value=((2)*parseInt(desks.value))+parseInt(pedestals.value)+parseInt(drawers.value)+((6)*parseInt(credenzas.value))+((6)*parseInt(cabinets.value))+parseInt(shelves.value)+((3)*parseInt(smbookcases.value))+((6)*parseInt(lgbookcases.value)); skates.value=Math.floor((((2)*parseInt(desks.value))+parseInt(pedestals.value)+parseInt(drawers.value)+((6)*parseInt(credenzas.value))+((6)*parseInt(cabinets.value))+parseInt(shelves.value)+((3)*parseInt(smbookcases.value))+((6)*parseInt(lgbookcases.value)))/3-0.1)+1">
```

In IE, clicking "Calculate" does not appear to do anything, while in the other browsers mentioned it seems to work 100% right (unless I'm missing something). Apologies for the rookie post, usually I just Google-warrior through this but I haven't had much luck so far.

Comment: please add the relevant code to your question instead of just posting a link. Also post the error messages.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Could you provide some information about what the specific issue with IE10 is?  It's generally accepted by the community that a question should contain some relevant code for coding issues such as these.  Thanks!

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) - No, you should not.

Comment: Good luck debugging your 700 characters single line.

Comment: IE I am getting crates is undefined. Much appreciate if you could share your javascript method. I see only the calculation definition on the onclick, with this i am unable to give solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the use of the `<output>` tag for displaying your results. As per [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp), this is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Use a `<span>` to display the results by using code similar to the following:

```
document.getElementById('skates').innerHTML = ....;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never attempted to use an output tag like that before but it was suggested on another forum so I blindly took the advice, serves me right for testing on IE last I guess.